# Почему нельзя говорить "березовый лес"?

Tags: лексика

Как известно, скопление берез называется роща и никак иначе. "Березовый лес" не говорят.
А почему, собственно? Мне кажется, что березы образуют целые леса (хотя для меня, жителя юга, когда больше пяти берез одновременно - уже большой березовый лес)))). По крайней мере, небольшой сосновый может быть - лесок, а вот березовая - обязательно роща.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему не говорят? Говорят, и в научной литературе тоже. Говорят ещё БЕРЕЗНЯК. А роща - небольшой лес. Берёзу как только не называют... Даже пионером леса - потому что плоды березы легко разносятся ветром. Она быстро идет в рост там, где на лесной вырубке еще не могут расти другие деревья. Но береза очень светолюбива и совершенно не выносит затенения. Поэтому обычно в лесу ее рано или поздно вытесняют другие деревья. Это ответ на вопрос, почему мало больших берёзовых лесов - за ними нужно ухаживать, прореживать, а с этим у нас проблема.

Comment: Надо же! А помню, что где-то читала, мол, "березовый лес" - это неграмотно.  
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Ни грамматических, ни смысловых препятствий нет. Это традиция. Берёзовые рощи в России не редкость, а вот леса... В Росии не знаю, а в Канаде есть.